ElasticSearch - search-as-you-type with fuzzy search
I have a Remix app with Vendure backend and and I'm trying to implement a search functionality that works like Google's.
https://i.imgur.com/9P3GLLC.gif
As you can see in the gif, when the user enters Amaz, it will get back the most relevant results, which being Amazon until the user makes a typo and enters Amazin. It still returns the most relevant fields, but when the user presses space, it will suggest Amazon Prime again.
What I want to implement in my Elasticsearch is the ability to do a search-as-you-type functionality with some fuzzy search. So when the user enters a product name that contains several words, even with a typo in any of them, Elasticsearch should know what was the user was trying to search up.
My index looks like this for the related productNameSearch field:
{
    "vendure-variantsadate": {
        "aliases": {
            "vendure-variants": {}
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "product-productNameSearch": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "productNameSearch": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "max_ngram_diff": "50",
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "vendure-variantsadate",
                "max_result_window": "50000",
                "creation_date": "adate",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "ngram": {
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram": "2",
                            "max_gram": "30"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "custom_search_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        },
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "ngram"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        },
                        "custom_autocomplete_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "ngram"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "someuuid",
                "version": {
                    "created": "sometime"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Also, I fed all the product names to Elasticsearch like this:
VeroDry Saniflow Hand Dryer - Satin Stainless Steel
VeroDry Saniflow Hand Dryer - White Enamel Finish
VeroDry Saniflow Hand Dryer - Brushed Aluminum
VeroDry Saniflow Hand Dryer - Push Button - Chrome
VendorMax Paper Towel Dispenser - White - Multi-Fold
VendorMax Paper Towel Dispenser - Stainless Steel - Satin Finish
VendorMax Smart Towel Cabinet - Silver
VendorMax Vision Toilet Brush - Matte Black
VendorMax Folded Paper Towel Dispenser - Matte Silver - C/Z Fold
Sanidor Touchless Soap Dispenser - Chrome Finish - 900ml
Sanidor Sanitizing Seat Spray - 400ml - Button-Activated
Sanidor Antibacterial Hand Soap - 700 ml - Refill
Sanidor Touchless Foam Soap Dispenser - 800ml - Black Steel
Sanidor Disinfectant Spray Dispenser - Wall Mounted - 1L
EnviroWipe Jumbo Roll Toilet Paper - 2-Ply - 22 cm Diameter
EnviroWipe Microfiber Cleaning Glove - General Use
EnviroWipe Glass Cleaning Glove - Microfiber
EnviroWipe Multi-Fold Paper Towels - 1-Ply - 80% Recycled
EnviroWipe Toilet Paper Dispenser - Stainless Steel - Satin Finish - Ø 300 mm

Each row is one string that represents a product.
How I expect it to work?

When I type in the char v I want to get back all the related
results, like VeroDry and VendorMax products.
When I type in Ver I want to get back all the related products,
VendorMax products the least relevant.
When I type in VeroDri, I get a suggestion for VeroDry, but if I continue to type in new characters, it should automatically return me values related to VeroDry and not an empty result list for VenoDri.

Here is the query I did in a script:
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=""

while true; do
  # Read single character from input
  IFS= read -rsn1 char

  # Append character to INPUT variable
  INPUT=$INPUT$char

  # Display the accumulated input
  echo "Searching for: $INPUT"

  # Perform the search query on Elasticsearch and store the result
  RESULT=$(curl --silent --location 'http://localhost:9200/vendure-variants/_search' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
      "size": 10,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "'"$INPUT"'",
                "type": "bool_prefix",
                "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                "fields": [
                  "productNameSearch",
                  "productNameSearch._2gram",
                  "productNameSearch._3gram"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }')



  if echo "$RESULT" | jq -e '.hits.hits | length > 0' > /dev/null; then
    echo "$RESULT" | jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source.productNameSearch' | grep -i "$INPUT"
  else
    echo "No results found for: $INPUT"
    echo "Elasticsearch response:"
    echo "$RESULT"
  fi
done


How it's working now?

When I type in Sani, I get back the results for VeroDry Saniflow products mainly, when I expect back Sanidor products as the most relevant results.
When I make a typo, it will result with no product found so somehow I want to implement fuzzy search too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
